# C#: How to write an expression with a dynamic parameter in Mapster

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, mapster

TLDR: Expression in `Mapster` config is invoked immediately, Is there any right way to invoke the executing the query?

I am using `mapster` to project the `efcore` entity to a `dto` in my project.

Originally I was doing this on my request handler which can do the job correctly, but according to `mapster` I should not be doing this due to performance issues. `TypeAdapterConfig` should only be defined in the code entry only once.

```
 // original code
 TypeAdapterConfig<ProductEntity, ProductDto>.NewConfig()
            .Map(d => d.Available, ProductExpression.AvailableForStoreId(request.ForStoreId));

 public static Expression<Func<ProductEntity, bool>> AvailableForStoreId(DefaultIdType storeId)
    {
        return s => s.ProductGroups.Any(gp => gp.storeRelProductGroup.Any(r => r.StoreId== storeId));
    }
```

for the reason above, I changed the code to follow the approach of using `MapContext.Current.Parameters["storeId"]` from [MapsterMapper](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/wiki/Setting-values)
and put the config in the code entry.

```
// Parameters approach 
TypeAdapterConfig<ProductEntity, ProductDto>.NewConfig()
            .Map(d => d.HasPricing, ProductExpression.AvailableForStoreId((int)MapContext.Current.Parameters["storeId"]));
```

But the problem is when I start the project, null reference error is thrown immediately for `MapContext.Current` as it's null.
Seems the expression is invoked on the `TypeAdapterConfig` being defined, so is there any way to fix the problem or what is the right way to keep `AvailableForStoreId` logic as an expression and supply the dynamic parameter(`storeId`) per request? thank you.